# How to requires variables from module in Node.js - getting Syntax error

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, server

I have a simple `node.js` https server and I would like to extract the certificate part into it's own module. But I'm getting a syntax error, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong..

```
certificate.cert
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

**app.js**

```
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const certificate = require('./certificate.js')

const app = express()

const server = https.createServer({
    certificate.cert,
    certificate.key,
}, app)

server.listen(443)
```

**certificate.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')

var certificate = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/privkey.pem'),
}

exports.certificate = certificate
```

When I `console.log(certificate)` I get this output

```
{
    certificate: {
        cert: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 51 12 47 49 4e 20 43 13 52 54 49 46 11 43 41 54 33 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 46 75 54 40 43 42 4b 47 60 41 77 49 42 44>,
        key: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 61 32 12 50 4e 30 40 52 49 56 41 54 45 20 4b 45 59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 31 49 49 45 61 51 49 40 41 44 41 4e 42 67 6b 71 68 6c>,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

> fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/cert.pem', 'utf8')

readFileSync returns Buffer if no enoding is defined

Comment: you did this for both, the key and the cert?

Comment: yes, it worked before I tried to separate it in 2 files but now when I added ````certificate.js```` it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var cert = require('./cert.js');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Now using https..');
});


var server = https.createServer(cert.certificate, app);

server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("server starting on port : " + 8000)
  console.log(cert.certificate)
});


module.exports = app:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is quite simple. As your log said, the object has a property `certificate`, which is another object with properties `cert` and `key`.

You should try this in your `app.js`:

```
const certificate = require('./certificate.js').certificate;

const server = https.createServer({
  certificate.cert,
  certificate.key,
}, app);
```

Or this one in `certificate.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/privkey.pem'),
};
```

Also, I'd suggest to always use `module.exports` (like [this blog post](https://blog.tableflip.io/the-difference-between-module-exports-and-exports/) says). Your error might be linked to this too.

Answer (score 0):

In **certificate.js** file

```
const fs = require('fs')

var certificate = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/privkey.pem'),
}

module.exports= certificate;
```